tsconfig for a Angular/NestJS monorepo
(Github example here)
I am trying to create a monorepo with 3 npm workspaces (not nx) :

@app/backend : A nestJS backend
@app/frontend : An Angular frontend
@app/shared : A shared library for DTOs and shared code

As an example, I export a variable answer in @app/shared and would like to import {  answer } from "@app/shared" from frontend and backend.
I am struggling with the tsconfig.
On Angular side, everything is fine, I can just import { answer } from '@app/shared'; and use it.
But on NestJS side, I get

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

After looking at other StackOverflow questions, I tried to use "type":"module" in package.json as long as various compilerOptions but I cannot find the right configuration. I always end up with a different error message. Also, I don't understand if I should change the tsconfig of @app/backend or @app/shared
After reading the Modules - Theory page of TypeScript documentation, I understand that the configuration in highly dependent on the host
Here, there are 2 hosts :

The frontend host is the browser
The backend is launched with npm start, which in turn calls nest start, which I believe uses ts-node under the hood, so the host would be ts-node

Here is how project is set up :
# Create the project directory
mkdir mono && cd mono
npm init -y

# Create the npm workspaces
npm init -y -w ./packages/frontend
npm init -y -w ./packages/backend
npm init -y -w ./packages/shared

# Install nestjs backend
# requires npm i -g @nestjs/cli
rm packages/backend/package.json
nest new @app/backend --directory packages/backend --skip-git --skip-install -p npm

# Install Angular frontend
# requires npm i -g @angular/cli
rm packages/frontend/package.json
ng new @app/frontend --directory packages/frontend --skip-git --skip-install --style scss --ssr false

# Replace index.js with index.ts in packages/shared/packages/json
sed -i 's/"main": "index.js"/"main": "index.ts"/g' "packages/shared/package.json"

# Add @app prefix to "shared" package.json
sed -i 's/"name": "shared"/"name": "@app\/shared"/g' "packages/shared/package.json"

# Add a dummy index.ts file in "shared" workspace
echo "export const answer = 42;" >> packages/shared/index.ts

# Install dependencies
npm i

# Add @app/shared as a dependency of frontend and backend
(cd packages/frontend && npm i @app/shared)
(cd packages/backend && npm i @app/shared)

